# Why i am not getting correct output.(php)

Tags: php

```
<?php
$count='a';
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
{
    for($j=1;$j<=(7-$i);$j++)
    {
        echo $count--;      
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    } 
?>
```

count++ is working correctly if i set count='a'. but count-- is not working.
what is the reason for it.

Comment: why `$count--`. it is a string!

Comment: You can increment characters using `++` but you can't decrement them using `--` because none of the PHP core team could figure out what should happen when you decremented `a`

Comment: What answer do you expect to get when you subtract 1 from 'a'?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [friendly manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). **Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented** and even so only plain ASCII alphabets and digits (a-z, A-Z and 0-9) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

(my emphasis)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$count='a';
for($i=1;$i<=6;$i++)
{
for($j=1;$j<=(7-$i);$j++)
{
    charMinus($count);
    echo $count;
}
echo "<br/>";
}

function charMinus(&$char) {
    $ascii=ord($char);
    $ascii==97 ? $ascii=123;
    $char=chr($ascii-1);
}
```